# How to configure my web application to run/read my custom TrustStore?

Tags: java, websphere, http-status-code-403, client-certificates, truststore

Good day,

I have a java web application in `Webphere`, and this web application need to call IBM third party to get some information.

IBM give me a `.p12` file which is contain of client cert, and I import it through WAS Console as a new `TrustStore` and set the management scope correct, through this step in WAS Console, `Security > SSL certificate and key management > Key stores and certificates`.

however, this new TrustStore never run/read by my application. So I keep hitting 403 Forbidden.

I suspect that I didnt configure it properly. kindly advise on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's actually a client certificate, you need to add it to a *Keystore*, not a *Truststore*. Truststore is where you put server certificates you want to trust, not client certificates you want to present.

And the easiest path would be to import it into one of the existing Keystores, rather than create a new one. e.g. CellDefaultKeyStore. Import as a "Personal certificate".

Update: don't give it the "default" alias, though. That will mess up WebSphere's own internal SSL communication. Instead give it another alias, and refer to that in the "Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configuration", to indicate that you want to use that specific alias when connecting to that specific destination

If you don't want to import into an existing Keystore, you can create a new one and and a new SSL configuration that uses it, and also reference *that* in a "Dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configuration". But unless you're managing a lot of different client certificates, that seems more complicated than is necessary.

Comment: They give me a .p12 file, so I think cant import into the existing CellDefaultKeyStore right? I am also create a new `dynamic outbound endpoint SSL configuration`, and a new `SSL setting`, and put in the specific destination in the outbound connection information there. But not sure why its looks like it didnt use my new created KeyStore, do u have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to import a .p12 file into existing Keystore.

Comment: @dbreaus, add the .p12 file into signer certificate in the existing KeyStore? but I will hit "signed fields invalid".

Comment: I manage to add the .p12 file into my NodeDefaultKeyStore and it take effect. But not sure why if I add it into CellDefaultTrustStore and its not working.

Comment: TrustStore is where you put other systems' (public portion of) server certificates to _trust_ them. KeyStore is where you put your own (private) client certificates to _present_ them.